# Jquery ui double image slider single command

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to make a double image slider commanded by the same button, but, with the code I have, I can't find how to select two different elements or all the instance on an element

html:

```
    <div class="slider-box">
    <div class="slider" id="slider">
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/animals" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 1 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/arch" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 2 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/nature" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 3 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/people" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 4 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/tech" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 5 Title</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider" id="slider">
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/animals" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 1 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/arch" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 2 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/nature" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 3 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/people" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 4 Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/tech" alt="">
            <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 5 Title</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="slider-nav">
        <div class="slider-nav__prev" id="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
        <div class="slider-nav__next" id="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
        <div class="slider-nav__dots" id="dots"></div>
    </div>
```

Js:

```
(function($) {

'use strict';

var pluginName = 'slider',
    defaults = {
        next: '.slider-nav__next',
        prev: '.slider-nav__prev',
        item: '.slider__item',
        dots: false,
        dotClass: 'slider__dot',
    };

function slider(element, options) {
    this.$document = $(document);
    this.$window = $(window);
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this.init();
}

slider.prototype.init = function() {
    this.setup();
    this.attachEventHandlers();
    this.update();
}

slider.prototype.setup = function(argument) {
    this.$slides = this.$element.find(this.options.item);
    this.count = this.$slides.length;
    this.index = 0;

    this.$next = $(this.options.next);
    this.$prev = $(this.options.prev);

    this.$canvas = $(document.createElement('div'));
    this.$canvas.addClass('slider__canvas').appendTo(this.$element);
    this.$slides.appendTo(this.$canvas);

    this.$dots = $(this.options.dots);
    this.$dots.length && this.createDots();
};

slider.prototype.createDots = function() {
    var dots = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.count; i += 1) {
        dots[i] = '<span data-index="' + i + '" class="' + this.options.dotClass + '"></span>';
    }
    this.$dots.append(dots);
}

slider.prototype.attachEventHandlers = function() {
    this.$element.on('prev.slider', this.prev.bind(this));
    this.$document.on('click', this.options.prev, (function(e) {
        this.$element.trigger('prev.slider');
    }).bind(this));

    this.$element.on('next.slider', this.next.bind(this));
    this.$document.on('click', this.options.next, (function(e) {
        this.$element.trigger('next.slider');
    }).bind(this));

    this.$element.on('update.slider', this.update.bind(this));
    this.$window.on('resize load', (function(e) {
        this.$element.trigger('update.slider');
    }).bind(this));

    this.$element.on('jump.slider', this.jump.bind(this));
    this.$document.on('click', ('.' + this.options.dotClass), (function(e) {
        var index = parseInt($(e.target).attr('data-index'));
        this.$element.trigger('jump.slider', index);
    }).bind(this));
};

slider.prototype.next = function(e) {
    this.index = (this.index + 1) % this.count;
    this.slide();
};

slider.prototype.prev = function(e) {
    this.index = Math.abs(this.index - 1 + this.count) % this.count;
    this.slide();
};

slider.prototype.jump = function(e, index) {
    this.index = index % this.count;
    this.slide();
}

slider.prototype.slide = function(index) {
    undefined == index && (index = this.index);
    var position = index * this.width * -1;
    this.$canvas.css({
        'transform': 'translate3d(' + position + 'px, 0, 0)',
    });
    this.updateCssClass();
};

slider.prototype.update = function() {
    this.width = this.$element.width();
    this.$canvas.width(this.width * this.count);
    this.$slides.width(this.width);
    this.slide();
};

slider.prototype.updateCssClass = function() {
    this.$slides
        .removeClass('active')
        .eq(this.index)
        .addClass('active');

    this.$dots
        .find('.' + this.options.dotClass)
        .removeClass('active')
        .eq(this.index)
        .addClass('active');
}

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        !$.data(this, pluginName) && $.data(this, pluginName, new slider(this, options));
    });
};

})(window.jQuery);

$('#slider').slider({
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
    dots: '#dots',
    autoplay: true,
});
```

I'm a javascript noob, I understand what I'm reading/using, but not sure when it's time to write.

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Fromager/zkgfzbcv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `id` should be unique, so replace both `id="slider"` with `id="slider1"` and `id="slider2"`.

2) Replace `#slider` with `.slider` at

```
$('.slider').slider({
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
    dots: '#dots',
    autoplay: true,
});
```

to set the `slider()` to both slides you have.

```js
(function($) {

'use strict';

var pluginName = 'slider',
    defaults = {
        next: '.slider-nav__next',
        prev: '.slider-nav__prev',
        item: '.slider__item',
        dots: false,
        dotClass: 'slider__dot',
    };

function slider(element, options) {
    this.$document = $(document);
    this.$window = $(window);
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this.init();
}

slider.prototype.init = function() {
    this.setup();
    this.attachEventHandlers();
    this.update();
}

slider.prototype.setup = function(argument) {
    this.$slides = this.$element.find(this.options.item);
    this.count = this.$slides.length;
    this.index = 0;

    this.$next = $(this.options.next);
    this.$prev = $(this.options.prev);

    this.$canvas = $(document.createElement('div'));
    this.$canvas.addClass('slider__canvas').appendTo(this.$element);
    this.$slides.appendTo(this.$canvas);

    this.$dots = $(this.options.dots);
    this.$dots.length && this.createDots();
};

let isInit = false; // check if the first slider is initialized

slider.prototype.createDots = function() {
    if(isInit){
      return; // if the first slider is initialized, do nothing.
    }
    var dots = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.count; i += 1) {
        dots[i] = '<span data-index="' + i + '" class="' + this.options.dotClass + '">';
        
        // $(this.$slides[i]) is the slider__item div
        dots[i] += i + '/' + $(this.$slides[i]).find('img').attr('src') + '</span>';
    }
    this.$dots.append(dots);
    isInit = true; // after the first slider is initialized, set to true
}

slider.prototype.attachEventHandlers = function() {
    this.$element.on('prev.slider', this.prev.bind(this));
    this.$document.on('click', this.options.prev, (function(e) {
        this.$element.trigger('prev.slider');
    }).bind(this));

    this.$element.on('next.slider', this.next.bind(this));
    this.$document.on('click', this.options.next, (function(e) {
        this.$element.trigger('next.slider');
    }).bind(this));

    this.$element.on('update.slider', this.update.bind(this));
    this.$window.on('resize load', (function(e) {
        this.$element.trigger('update.slider');
    }).bind(this));

    this.$element.on('jump.slider', this.jump.bind(this));
    this.$document.on('click', ('.' + this.options.dotClass), (function(e) {
        var index = parseInt($(e.target).attr('data-index'));
        this.$element.trigger('jump.slider', index);
    }).bind(this));
};

slider.prototype.next = function(e) {
    this.index = (this.index + 1) % this.count;
    this.slide();
};

slider.prototype.prev = function(e) {
    this.index = Math.abs(this.index - 1 + this.count) % this.count;
    this.slide();
};

slider.prototype.jump = function(e, index) {
    this.index = index % this.count;
    this.slide();
}

slider.prototype.slide = function(index) {
    undefined == index && (index = this.index);
    var position = index * this.width * -1;
    this.$canvas.css({
        'transform': 'translate3d(' + position + 'px, 0, 0)',
    });
    this.updateCssClass();
};

slider.prototype.update = function() {
    this.width = this.$element.width();
    this.$canvas.width(this.width * this.count);
    this.$slides.width(this.width);
    this.slide();
};

slider.prototype.updateCssClass = function() {
    this.$slides
        .removeClass('active')
        .eq(this.index)
        .addClass('active');

    this.$dots
        .find('.' + this.options.dotClass)
        .removeClass('active')
        .eq(this.index)
        .addClass('active');
}

$.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        !$.data(this, pluginName) && $.data(this, pluginName, new slider(this, options));
    });
};

})(window.jQuery);

let isInitialized = false;

$('.slider').slider({
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
    dots: '#dots',
    autoplay: true,
});
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.slider-box,
.slider__item {
    position: relative;
}

.slider-box{
  display:flex;
}

.slider {
  width:40vw;
  display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__canvas {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.slider__item {
    float: left;
}

.slider__item__title {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    /*transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -60%, 0);*/
}

.active .slider__item__title {
    opacity: 1;
    /*transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);*/
}

.slider-nav {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider-nav__dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}

.slider-nav__prev,
.slider-nav__next,
.slider__dot {
    background:green;
    /*backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;*/
}

.slider-nav__prev,
.slider-nav__next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-top: -1.5rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
}

.slider-nav__prev {
    left: 7%;
}

.slider-nav__next {
    right: 7%;
}

.slider__dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
/*
.slider-nav__prev:hover,
.slider-nav__next:hover,
.slider__dot.active,
.slider__dot:hover {
    transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1);
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slider" id="slider1">
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/animals" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 1 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/arch" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 2 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/nature" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 3 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/people" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 4 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/tech" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 5 Title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider" id="slider2">
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/animals" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 1 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/arch" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 2 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/nature" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 3 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/people" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 4 Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/960/540/tech" alt="">
      <h2 class="slider__item__title">Slide 5 Title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-nav">
  <div class="slider-nav__prev" id="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
  <div class="slider-nav__next" id="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
  <div class="slider-nav__dots" id="dots"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And is it possible with the separation of Id to score just one série of dots and not double them ?

Comment: @FlorianFromager As per your comment, I updated the answer and edited `createDots()` a little bit.

Comment: If I wanna extract the title or alt or data-title of the first slide to put it in dots, may I do something like `dots[i] = '<span data-index="' + i + '" class="' + this.options.dotClass + '">' + i + '/' + this.slider__item__title + '</span>';` or `dots[i] = '<span data-index="' + i + '" class="' + this.options.dotClass + '">' + i + '/' + this.data(title) + '</span>';`

Comment: @FlorianFromager I updated in the comments, you can get the attributes using the same way.

Comment: Ok, then with .find I can do lot of things like that

Comment: A typo there, fixed.

Comment: If I wan't to jump from 3 to 5 in the dots (not mark the 4), can I put a class on the image to say : `this.not('.class').count`

Comment: Well, this is one of the basic question about for loop. [Please take a look.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Comment: Yeah, I see, I tried something like that
`$(this.$slides[i]).each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('alt') == $(this).prev().attr('alt')) {
          dots[i] = '<li data-index="' + i  + '">&nbsp;' + $(this.$slides[i]).find('img').data('title') + '</li>';
          console.log('nope');
          return false;
        } else { 
          console.log($(this).attr('alt'));
          return true;
        }
      });`
But I think there is a problem with [i], I search